# switch case with byte datatype

Tags: java

The Range of byte is -128 to 127.But in following code it is going beyond the byte range and the output of code is "Thank you".

class Solve {

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        byte by=10;

        switch(by+118) {//here it go beyond the byte range.

            default:System.out.println("Sunday");

            case 0:System.out.println("Monday");

            case 128:System.out.println("Thank u");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The 118 (which is called a literal) is an int by default.

When you add the 118 (which is an int) to your byte, the result is stored in an int. That means your switch statement contains an int.

All of the other literals (0 and 128) are also ints.

Note that if you did keep the result in a byte variable, you would experience overflow, and the value would wrap around. Try this code out, which has been cleaned up to include the necessary break statements as well:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        byte by=10;
        byte result = (byte) (by + 118);

        System.out.println("Result: " + result);

        switch(result){

        default:
            System.out.println("default");
            break;

        case 0:
            System.out.println("0");
            break;

        case -128:
            System.out.println("-128");
            break;

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons:

1. Because the `118` literal is an `int`, and adding a byte and an `int` results in an `int`, not a `byte`. (All numeric literals without a `.` or a suffix are `int` in Java.)
2. Because you're missing `break` statements on your other cases, so no matter **what** value you end up switching on, you're going to see that "Thank u" output, as `case` statements are run in order starting with the first matching one.

Amusingly, even if you forced all of your numbers to be `byte`s, you'd still end up doing the "Thank u" route:

```
class Solve {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        byte by=10;

        switch((byte)(by+118)) {

            default:System.out.println("Sunday");

            case (byte)0:System.out.println("Monday");

            case (byte)128:System.out.println("Thank u");

        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Thank u
```

That's because `(byte)128` has the value `(byte)-128` (yes, negative) because it overflows its `byte` container and wraps around, as does `(byte)((byte)10 + 118)`. So even though you wrote `case (byte)128:` in the source, it really uses `-128`. You can see this easily enough:

```
System.out.println((byte)128 == (byte)-128);
```

Output:

```
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are switching on an int, not a byte.